# Merge similar columns or not to create the multiple columns with similar column names while flattening JSON

Tags: python, json, json-flattener

When flatten JSON, i am getting columns with values as:

```
{'0_extension_0_url': 'http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation', '0_extension_0_extension_0_url': 'latitude', '0_extension_0_extension_0_valueDecimal': 42.06768934464684, '0_extension_0_extension_1_url': 'longitude', '0_extension_0_extension_1_valueDecimal': -71.17560251863814, '0_line_0': 'ratna', '0_city': 'Sharon', '0_state': 'MA', '0_postalCode': '02067', '0_country': 'US'}
```

desired output in CSV format:

```
extension_url, extension_extension_url, extension_extension_valueDecimal_latitude, extension_extension_valueDecimal_longitude, line, city, state, postalCode, country
http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation,42.06768934464684, -71.17560251863814, ratna, Sharon, MA, 02067, US
```

Below JSON data is a part of JSON data:

```
      "address": [ {
        "extension": [ {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation",
          "extension": [ {
            "url": "latitude",
            "valueDecimal": 42.06768934464684
          }, {
            "url": "longitude",
            "valueDecimal": -71.17560251863814
          } ]
        } ],
        "line": [ "350 Frami Trafficway" ],
        "city": "Sharon",
        "state": "MA",
        "postalCode": "02067",
        "country": "US"
      } ],
```

python code:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

I am expecting to create only single field name, without JSON location keys and group the values (if more than one) under the given field name, to create tabular form of data.

Comment: Your JSON contains arrays. If you don't add the indexes to the keys, you'll get duplicate keys when the arrays have more than one element.

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid dictionary. You have several values with no keys before them, like `'longitude'`

Comment: My object is to convert the data to tabular format. I want to merge the duplicate keys  as values are different. 

for the desired output:
```

Comment: I have also updated the desired output to CSV as well

Comment: The CSV has 9 column headers but only 8 values. Is `http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation` supposed to be in the `extension_extension_url` column?

Comment: How is the algorithm supposed to know that `latitutude` and `longitude` become part of the column name, they're not values in the row?

Comment: Where does `rev1` come from?

Comment: Thank you for the correction, i have updated the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

- you can remove the index code, add break the list logic code to it, depends on what you real need.
- base on the desired output example code.

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            if len(x)>1:
                for a in x:
                    out[name + list(a.values())[0]] = list(a.values())[1]
            else:
                for a in x:
                    flatten(a, name)
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

import json
import csv

f = open('test.json')
data = json.load(f)
data = flatten_json(data)
print(data)
f.close()
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, data.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(data)
```

- result:

```
{'address_extension_url': 'http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation', 'address_extension_extension_latitude': 42.06768934464684, 'address_extension_extension_longitude': -71.17560251863814, 'address_line': '350 Frami Trafficway', 'address_city': 'Sharon', 'address_state': 'MA', 'address_postalCode': '02067', 'address_country': 'US'}
```

- csv result:

```
address_extension_url,address_extension_extension_latitude,address_extension_extension_longitude,address_line,address_city,address_state,address_postalCode,address_country
http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation,42.06768934464684,-71.17560251863814,350 Frami Trafficway,Sharon,MA,02067,US
```